# Project Online read-only Error

Tags: ms-office, office365, sharepoint-2013, projects

I am having a problem with Microsoft Projects (Online Only). Getting the error as shown in the image below. Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem on this blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brismith/2018/03/05/project-online-why-might-my-site-go-read-only/

In my case, the issue was that I required at least one Project Online Professional or Premium license to keep the Free Projects Online for EDU working.